# Xsd recursion of complexTypes

Tags: xsd, xml-validation

I am just learning XML/XSD and am struggling with the implementation of an XML-schema which models a folder structure. 
What I had in mind was defining a complexType for the folder which can have additional folder instances that represent subfolders. Using the xsd schema validator [here](http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate/) always returns that the schema is invalid.

I tried defining the complexType up front and then using the *ref* keyword for subfolders:

```
<xs:complexType name="tFolder">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Path" type="tFolderType" msdata:Ordinal="0" />                    
  <xs:element ref="Folder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  <xs:element name="File" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="File_Text" msdata:Ordinal="0">
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>                              
 </xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="Type" type="tFolderType" />
```

As for the element itself:

```
<xs:element name="Folder" type="tFolder" />
```

The error returned by the validator is:

**"Cannot resolve the name 'Folder' to a(n) 'element declaration' component."**

and the error occurs at the line

```
<xs:element ref="Folder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

Defining the complexType within the element itself yields the exact same error:

```
<xs:element name="Folder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Path" type="tFolderType" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
      <xs:element ref="Folder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />                          
      <xs:element name="File" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="File_Text" msdata:Ordinal="0">
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>                              
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Type" type="tFolderType" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

What I've read, this kind of recursion should work using *ref*.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? Maybe the xsd validator is just faulty? If so, does anyone know a better alternative? I've tried using the one from w3.org as well, but it seems to be taken offline...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the way to do it (don't use ref):

```
<element name="test" type="tns:TestType"></element>

<complexType name="TestType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="test" type="tns:TestType"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Comment: Why shouldn't one use ref?

Comment: My answer is the usual reference between element and type definition. I personally haven't used ref, so I can't recommend it. Did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448888/what-does-the-ref-attribute-on-an-element-in-an-xsd-do